# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'USER_NAME' in 'where clause' - container managed authentication

Tags: hibernate, jsf, tomcat, authentication, servlet-filters

After I asked the question - [Authorization and authentication on the web application with JSF, Hibernate and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087056/authorization-and-authentication-on-the-web-application-with-jsf-hibernate-and), I developed some code and I believe that I am very close to the solution.

First of all, I am programming a Web-Application with Java EE, JSF, Hibernate, MySQL by using Eclipse and Apache Tomcat. I do not use Spring, EJB or etc. I implement "Container Managed Authentication". I share some parts of code from the project. ***THEY HAVE STANDART SIMPLE CODES TO DEVELOP SERVLET LOGIN. WHEN YOU LOOK AT THEM, YOU WILL UNDERSTAND ALL EASILY.***

POJO classes;

```
public class User {

    // Primary Key
    private int USER_ID;
    
    private String USER_NAME;
    private String PASSWORD;
    private String FIRST_NAME;
    private String LAST_NAME;
    ...

    public User(String uSER_NAME, String pASSWORD, String fIRST_NAME,
            String lAST_NAME, ...) {
        super();
        USER_NAME = uSER_NAME;
        PASSWORD = pASSWORD;
        FIRST_NAME = fIRST_NAME;
        ...
    }

    /**
     * Default empty constructor needed for hibernate entity
     */
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * Getters and setters
     */
        ...
        ...
}

public class UserGroup {

// Primary Key
private int USER_GROUP_ID;

// Reference for User table - foreign key
private Set<User> USERS;

private String USER_GROUP_NAME;

private boolean ADMINISTRATOR_SCR;
private boolean USER_SCR;
private boolean PLANNING_SCR;
...

public UserGroup(Set<User> uSERS, String uSER_GROUP_NAME,
        boolean aDMINISTRATOR_SCR, boolean uSER_SCR, boolean pLANNING_SCR,
        ...) {
    super();
    USERS = uSERS;
    USER_GROUP_NAME = uSER_GROUP_NAME;
    ADMINISTRATOR_SCR = aDMINISTRATOR_SCR;
    ...
}

/**
 * Default empty constructor needed for hibernate entity
 */
public UserGroup() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
/**
 * Getters and setters
 */
    ...
    ...
}
```

Hibernate mapping files;

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="folder.User" table="USER">
    <id name="USER_ID" type="int">
        <column name="USER_ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="USER_NAME" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="USER_NAME" />
    </property>
        <property name="PASSWORD" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PASSWORD" />
        </property>
        <property name="FIRST_NAME" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FIRST_NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="LAST_NAME" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LAST_NAME" />
       ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="folder.UserGroup" table="USERGROUP">
        <id name="USER_GROUP_ID" type="int">
            <column name="USER_GROUP_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <set name="USERS" table="USER" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="USER_GROUP_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="folder.User" />
        </set>
        <property name="USER_GROUP_NAME" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="USER_GROUP_NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="ADMINISTRATOR_SCR" type="boolean">
            <column name="ADMINISTRATOR_SCR" />
        </property>
        <property name="USER_SCR" type="boolean">
            <column name="USER_SCR" />
        </property>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

web.xml configuration;

```
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restricted</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restricted Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/authorized/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

server.xml tomcat configuration;

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
       driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/authentication_db"
       connectionName="..." connectionPassword="..."
       userTable="user" userNameCol="USER_NAME" userCredCol="PASSWORD" 
       userRoleTable="usergroup" roleNameCol="USER_GROUP_NAME" />
```

Lastly, login function;

```
public String login(){
        
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            //Login via the Servlet Context
            request.login(getLoginName(), getLoginPass());
       

            return "success";
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid Login", null));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "failure";
}
```

After I put records on User table and UserGroup and I run the app, it looks like working properly. However, I get this error;

> Nis 16, 2014 4:38:48 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm getRoles
>
> SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
> column 'USER_NAME' in 'where clause'
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> Source)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> Source)
> ... ...

Please help me!

**EDIT:**

*MySQL Table Definition:*

> *Table:* user
>
> *Columns:*
>
> USER_ID     int(11) AI PK
>
> USER_NAME   varchar(255)
>
> PASSWORD    varchar(255)
>
> FIRST_NAME  varchar(255)
>
> LAST_NAME   varchar(255)
>
> ...
>
> EMAIL       varchar(255)
>
> USER_GROUP_ID int(11) FK (UserGroup Table -> USER_GROUP_ID)
>
> ---
>
> *Table:* usergroup
>
> *Columns:*
>
> USER_GROUP_ID     int(11) AI PK
>
> USER_GROUP_NAME   varchar(255)
>
> ADMINISTRATOR_SCR bit(1)
>
> USER_SCR          bit(1)
>
> PLANNING_SCR      bit(1) ...

Comment: Could you post the MySql table definition also ?

Comment: I added MySQL table information. They are all generated by using persistence feature of hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem is about JDBCRealm data format. JDBCRealm is an implementation of the Tomcat 6 Realm interface that looks up users in a relational database accessed via a JDBC driver. I have to create user and user group tables in a special format to use JDBCRealm. To view this configuration, visit the page of Apache Tomcat web site - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html.